# Rails Paperclip add a image size when checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a model of attachments that belongs to the asset model.   The asset model can have a main image, which will be scaled image that only exists if the main_image checkbox is checked.  I want to add this size to paperclip, but I don't know how.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do so far is to use attachment_on_the_fly gem which will only generate the image if main_image gets displayed.  The original gem has a couple errors and I have fixed and set a pull request for them but it is not up to date with my fork so you can find it on https://github.com/plowdawg/Attachment-on-the-Fly which fixes a bug making it fail on Windows machines and fixes a bug that requires you to name the attachment attachment on the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ryan Bates describes what you're looking for in his RailsCast for Paperclip.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip